# Why was this question not reconsidered after editing?

Tags: discussion, support

Why was this question changed from hold to closed and no feedback provided after edits were made?

It was originally put on hold as off topic, so I updated the question and restructured it to try and better comply with the guidelines.

Then after my edits it went from hold to closed with no feedback, even after directly asking for consideration from more than one of the mods who voted on the question.

[How to brightly light an entire backyard area with only one electrical box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138951/how-to-brightly-light-an-entire-backyard-area-with-only-one-electrical-box)

The votes were cast by @ThreePhaseEel, @Tyson, @Daniel Griscom, @RedGrittyBrick, and @mmathis

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: It looks like the question sat in the reopen queue too long, and so was automatically moved from on-hold to closed.

Comment: This stack is slightly hampered by a lack of users that are active in the review queues.  Most questions/answers get 3-4 review votes (Close, Reopen, flag, etc.), and never reach the 5 vote threshold. In this case, your question actually got the 5 votes required to put it on hold.  However, after you edited it, it did not get the required 5 votes to reopen it.

Comment: @Tester101 thank you for explaining how it worked.  However the fact remains after editing I see no reason for it to be disallowed from the site yet it sounds like it won't be reviewed to the extent, for example, it would be on SO.  So does this mean the best thing to do is to simply ask the question from scratch?  At the worst it could be eventually marked duplicate in that case.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid the question was not reopened, because even after the edit, it was still off topic.

The first part of your question seems to be looking for a product to solve the problem. This type of question is off topic, and should be closed as a "shop for me" type question. Then at the end, you seem to be fishing for any type of solution.  Which in this format, could be closed as too broad.

This site works best with simple, well focused questions. Asking for ideas on how to solve a problem, is not a good fit for this format.  Basically, this site is useful for questions like "*I'm doing this thing, and this little part of the project has me confused. How do I do this one simple thing?*". Rather than "*Here's a broad overview of what I'd like to accomplish, how can I accomplish this?*".  The second type of question is far too broad, to be answered in a few minutes, by volunteers on the internet.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Questions are  not allowed to seek product recommendations, This is completely different from asking questions which may happen to recommend types of products in general.  for example someone could ask how do I make a light do X, and the answer might be to buy a switch, this is totally different than asking which type of switch should I buy.

Comment: Your second point is also incorrect in fact, provably so.  About the question being too broad to be answered concisely on the Internet in this format. in all the time this question has been stagnating I found a simple solution that worked and could’ve been described here to help others with a short description.

Comment: I believe what actually happened here is you simply do not wish to reverse the decision which is already been made, or are suffering from exposure bias https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere-exposure_effect.  This is one of the reasons this stacks growth is being held back.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, and I'm sorry my logic is flawed.

Answer (score 3):

A question goes from being marked as [on hold] to [closed] automatically after 5 days.

There is no real change of state. The question is still closed, but the name has changed to reflect the fact that after this time the question is more likely to remain closed.

You did the right thing by editing, but as Tester101 pointed out, there aren't enough people reviewing the reopen queue to get the required number of reopen votes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ChrisF I appreciate it. I upvoted it because it was helpful, however I can't consider it an answer yet because it doesn't make sense that questions are determined to not be reopened possibly due to what is a lower community population. See also my comment to Tester101 above.